# Bash: execute a multi-command line string in a script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

There is, in a file, some multi-command line like this:

```
cd /home/user; ls
```

In a bash script, I would like to execute these commands, adding some arguments to the last one. For example:

```
cd /home/user; ls   -l *.png
```

I thought it would be enough to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
commandLine="$(cat theFileWithCommandInside)   -l *.png"
$commandLine
exit 0
```

But it says:

```
/home/user;: No such file or directory
```

In other words, the ";" character doesn't mean anymore "end of the command": The shell is trying to find a directory called "user;" in the home folder...

I tried to replace ";"  with "&&", but the result is the same.

Comment: Not working... the same error occurs. But thanks for proposing something :)

Comment: ahh... sorry, that was typo, it should be `bash -c ...`

Comment: Yeeeear! Many thanks! Would you please post it as an answer so that I can validate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the point of your question is to execute command stored in string. there are thousands of ways to execute that indirectly. but eventually, bash has to involve.

so why not explicitly invoke bash to do the job?

```
bash -c "$commandLine"
```

from doc:

> -c string
>
> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Answer (score 2):

The key is: `eval`

Here, the fixed script (look at the third line):

```
#!/bin/bash
commandLine="$(cat theFileWithCommandInside)   -l *.png"
eval $commandLine
exit 0
```

Comment: It's also pretty dangerous to use `eval`. You'd be better off taking the approach on the other answer.

Comment: Aha. OK. In that case I will implement a REGEX condition checking if the command line do exactly what it has to do.
This is not to be shared to everyone, but only at work for some specific scientific program.

Comment: -1 `eval` may work for you and even be appropriate under circumstances that are limited and specific to your needs, but it is pernicious for the _general_ question, for a visitor to this site looking for the answer to a similar question. If you need to open the door for your script to change, then parameterize it – define the interface that you need to and constrain the change that it can support.

Comment: @kojiro: So, should I validate the safe answer given by Dragan or the one which I will use in real life? :)

Comment: To be clear, the command file contains command(s) necessary to launch a program. The problem is that it can be installed in different ways. Sometimes, a single command is enough. Sometimes, a file has to be sourced. I don't see how to "parametrize" it better than saying "give me the command(s) to launch it in some file". As said before, it's for working, not for sharing.

Comment: @taalf 1. You must do what you think is right, of course – Obi Wan. 2. IMO I think you should wait to accept an answer. Maybe a third or fourth person will post something better? Leave the door open for competition. 3. If it were up to me and I had to accept something now, I would accept Dragan's answer, but you probably already knew that from my previous comment.

Comment: @taalf `"it's for working, not for sharing."` Whilst that may be the case, StackOverflow is a public resource and it's purpose is to serve as a knowledge base. Therefore you should assume that anything you post here will be consumed as something that's been shared for public reference. So, as you're seeing, its highly likely the community may advise or act against what might be perfect for your specific situation.

Comment: @arco444: I understand that security is important when you want to share your code with unknown people, but sometimes security is not so important, because you know the people who will use it.
So, the 'eval' solution is suitable not only for my specific case, but for any case in which the code won't be shared and used by careful people.
This is what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you execute the commands themselves in the script, instead of "importing" them?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user; ls -l *.png
exit 0
```

Comment: Because the content of the command file will be frequently modified, by several users, and I want to avoid modifying my bash script.

Comment: By the way, I found the solution... (above)

Comment: @taalf That's **exactly** one of the cases why you should **avoid** using `eval`. Any user can put any command in the file and it will get executed. It's a potentially big security risk...

Comment: @taalf, if the command file is going to be modified frequently,how do you know your usage of it will not break?

Comment: @arco444 I can't see how this security risk becomes smaller when the commands are executed without using `eval`. If code like the OP requests should be run, then its source must be trusted.

Comment: @MichaelJaros because if commands are being sourced from a file that other users are changing, OP has no control over what is being executed. In certain situations this is obviously a security risk. It's not necessarily *wrong* to use `eval` as multiple other comments have acknowledged, but it's best avoided.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but this is not specific to `eval`. Untrusted code is a security risk, whether executed directly, using `eval`, or using `source`. But as I see now you were probably referring to Dragan's answer which of course eliminates the security risk. Unfortunately this approach does not meet the (later added) requirement of not having to modify the main script when the contributed code changes.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the command into a function:

```
function doLS() {
    cd user; ls $@
}
```

`$@` expands to all arguments passed to the function. If you (or the snippet authors) add functions expecting a predefined number of arguments, you may find the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, ... useful instead.

As the maintainer of the main script, you will have to make sure that everyone providing such a snippet provides that "interface" your code uses (i.e. their code defines the functions your program calls and their functions process the arguments your program passes).

Use `source` or `.` to import the function into your running shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
source theFileWithCommandInside
doLS -l *.png
exit 0
```

I'd like to add a few thoughts on the `;` topic:

> In other words, the ";" character doesn't mean anymore "end of the
>   command": The shell is trying to find a directory called "user;" in
>   the home folder...

`;` is not used to terminate a statement as in C-style languages. Instead it is used to separate commands that should be executed sequentially inside a **list**. Example executing two commands in a subshell:

```
( command1 ; command2 )
```

If the list is part of a **group**, it must be succeeded by a `;`:

```
{ command1 ; command2 ; }
```

In your example, tokenization and globbing (replacing the `*`) will not be executed (as you may have expected), so your code will not be run successfully.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer, but how to mix the `source` command with the need to add some arguments to the last command of the line?

Comment: oh, sorry, I have misunderstood that important part of your question. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @taalf answer is modified.

Comment: @Michael_Jaros Thanks!
Last question, however: is this solution safer than the `eval` one?... Or just: why this one would be better than the `eval` one?...

Comment: @taalf Ad 1) It does not matter how you include code in your program. If it comes from an untrusted source, it can become a threat to security. From a security point of view, `eval` is not any more evil than `source`, simply executing other programs or loading lines of code into a variable and then executing them.

Comment: In other circumstances, `eval==evil` may still be true because it could execute code without the developer's intent.

Comment: Ad 2) From a maintainability point of view, `eval` is often found in code that could be classified as a dirty hack (unreadable, prone to side-effects). It basically allows executing code that does not have to be defined at compile time, and that is something you should generally avoid when building robust software. In your example the `source` approach has the advantage of supporting multi-line scripts without any workarounds. Of course Dragan's approach would eliminate any security concerns, but it would not meet your collaboration requirements (contributions, no modification of main script).

Answer (score 0):

Using the <(...) form

sh <(sed 's/$/ *.png/' theFileWithCommandInside)

Comment: bash <(sed 's/$/  *.png/' theFileWithCommandInside) works too... This uses the process substitution features. The output of the sed command is put into a temporary file - and the file name is passed as a script name to bash.